# Angular component load time

Tags: angular, frontend

How can I get time that component takes to load ? I thought about starting and stoping some kind of timer in the lifecycle hooks but I'm not sure it will work.
I need to know time when component is fully loaded, with all the children and data fetched from server.

Comment: That would depend on what `loaded` means. Perhaps you could implement an interface on child components and have the parent component iterate over all child components that implement that interface. The interface implementation would be some method that returns an observable<boolean> where it emits true when it is finished loading. Once your observable streams all return true you are done. You would need a timer or something similar to start and stop (or take a begin time and a end time and then get the difference).

Comment: As the implementations may vary significantly and there is no standard way to do this I think this question will likely be marked as closed because it is to broad and not a good fit for [so].

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, loaded means that page is 'ready for the user' - no spinners, all data fetched. I thought about something similar that you wrote but I wonder how it will affect the performance.